# What are the major structures of the medial temporal lobe?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging

Basic question here from a behavioral researcher: What are the major structures of the medial temporal lobe (MTL)? Can anyone link to a good diagram of these structures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MTL consists of (note that some structures overlap):

- cortical areas, which can be categorized in at least three ways:

  - portions of two gyri

    - entire [parahippocampal gyrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parahippocampal_gyrus)
    - anterior medial side of [fusiform gyrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusiform_gyrus)
  - five named cortical areas:

    - [perirhinal cortex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perirhinal_cortex)
    - parahippocampal cortex (see [parahippocampal gyrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parahippocampal_gyrus))
    - [entorhinal cortex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorhinal_cortex)
    - [presubiculum](http://braininfo.rprc.washington.edu/CentralDirectory.aspx?ID=167&questID=2302)*
    - [parasubiculum](http://braininfo.rprc.washington.edu/CentralDirectory.aspx?ID=2304&questID=2302)*
  - five [Brodmann areas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brodmann_area): 27, 28, 34, 35, 36
- [hippocampus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocampus)
- [amygdala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amygdala)*

* indicates that not all literature includes this component in the MTL

I didn't find a diagram of only the MTL. The best diagrams I found were (not shown here because I don't own the copyright):

- [Figure 1](http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/dl/free/0071402357/156721/figure350_1.gif)
- [Figure 2](http://introspectional.com/section2/images/limbic3a.gif)
- [Figure 3](http://neuropolitics.org/TemporalLobe.gif)

#### References

> - Brodmann, K. (1909) Vergleichende Lokalisationslehre der Grosshirnrinde in ihren Prinzipien dargestellt auf Grund des
>     Zellenbaues. Leipzig : Johann Ambrosius Barth.
> - Squire, L.R., Stark, C.E.L., & Clark, R.E. (2004) The Medial Temporal Lobe. Annu. Rev. Neurosci. 27:279–306
>     [[pdf](http://whoville.ucsd.edu/PDFs/383_Squire_etal_%20AnnRevNeurosci2004.pdf)]